# Counting number of True and False on a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:-

```
    col1   col2   col3   col4
0   True  False  False  False
1   True   True  False  False
2   True  False  False   True
3  False  False   True  False
4   True  False  False  False
5   True  False  False  False
6   True  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False
8   True  False   True  False
```

I need to count the number of True in a row. If that is greater than 1 , the output should be a `False`.

How can I get this
In my case, output would be-:

```
0     True
1     False
2     False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     False
8     False
```

Comment: df.sum(1).eq(1)

Comment: @W-B: Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @Bazingaa Aaaahhhh, this is one of those questions that seems so stupidly simple, it must be a dupe of _something_. I imagine that's W-B's hesitancy to answer.

Comment: @Bazingaa way too generic .. and lazy to find a dup ... that is where the comment from .. :-)

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387524/counting-the-amount-of-true-false-values-in-a-pandas-row) with a changed axis.

Comment: One of those instances where the flaw of the StackOverflow culture manifests itself... it's a much easier effort to provide a simple answer in comment than to dig for a sure-fire duplicate question or post a seemingly *too simple* answer.  It helps the OP while not being too demeaning in the approach.

Comment: I didn't know it would be so simple .. This works . Thanks @W-B

Comment: Can you explain a bit how does sum(1) and eq(1) works usually , if its okay ?

Comment: check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html